# Don't change interface of Button when clicked

Tags: css, button, bootstrap-4

Disclaimer: Never worked with CSS before, first time having a front end task related to styling so I'm sorry for any misconceptions, wrong usage of words etc.

I'm having this dummy button that opens up a Modal (1):

[image]

So when I click it, a modal pops up and the button becomes like this (2):

[image]

As you can see, the button has a border (?) when clicked, looks like it's a click held or whatever. So when the modal is opened, if I click anywhere on the screen the button turns to (3):

[image]

No border in this picture like in (2). This is a simple `button` component:

```js
<button className={`btn position-relative  ${className}`} onClick={onClick}>
...
</button>
```

and the component where it opens the Modal has the following code:

```js
<Button onClick={() => setModal(true)} className={'btn btn-primary mr-2'}>
  (info icon)
</Button>
```

Do you know how can I achieve after clicking (1) to make the button like in (3) and not like in (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap ( from it's partial scss file `_buttons.scss` ) adds a box-shadow ( blueish color) by default to the button when focused ( = clicked )

This is the style

```
 .btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(0 123 255 / 25%);
 }
```

So what you should do is remove that ( overwrite it ) in your own stylesheet. Keep in mind that you should use a more specific selector. Using just `.btn:focus { }`  won't overwrite it. In the example below i used the tag name also `button.btn:focus {}`

```css
button.btn:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

P.S.
You can 'inspect' the styles added on different states ( hover, focus, active ) on any element using the dev tools provided by each modern browser

Answer (score 0):

try this ______________________________________________________

```css
.btn-primary:focus{
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```